# How to use functions in generated columns?

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL 5.7 and I do not have an access to methods introduced in 8.0.

Therefore I'd like to do something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_to_bin(uuid CHAR(36))
  RETURNS BINARY(16) DETERMINISTIC
  RETURN concat(
      substr(unhex(replace(uuid, '-', '')), 7, 2),
      substr(unhex(replace(uuid, '-', '')), 5, 2),
      substr(unhex(replace(uuid, '-', '')), 1, 4),
      substr(unhex(replace(uuid, '-', '')), 9, 8));

CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id`        BINARY(16) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (uuid_to_bin(document->>'$.id')) STORED NOT NULL,
  `document`  JSON                                                                   NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

However when i run given sql it throws an error:
`[2017-11-01 14:12:41] [HY000][3102] Expression of generated column 'id' contains a disallowed function.`

Even thought the function is **deterministic**. How can I do that ?

I called my function `uuid_to_bin` because if in the future I'll be able to upgrade my MYSQL server to 8.0 I do not want to change the sql for my columns

Also maybe this be a reason ? `COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html - Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules. An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.

Literals, **deterministic built-in functions**, and operators are permitted..
Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and **user-defined functions are not permitted**.

You may not find the last one in verbatim in the documentation. However,
[CREATE FUNCTION page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function.html) says

> The CREATE FUNCTION statement is used to create **stored** functions and **loadable** functions

While the other page above explicitly says:

> Stored functions and loadable functions are not permitted.

Comment: so i do have to repeat that part (function body) on every table i want to generate that kind of binary uuid

Comment: perhaps You could create a view using the function per table without/instead of the generated column?